# Определить движок

Tags: url, cms, service

Есть ли такой сервис или что-то в этом роде, типо... Вписываешь: ?direct=search&keyword=

А он тебе выдает какой это движок может быть или список..

Есть что то в этом роде?

Comment: Возможно, поможет плагин Wappalyzer для Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

прямо по ссылке http://2ip.ru/cms/